# jQuery conflict between slider and google search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having conflict with some parts of my coding involving jQuery:

## 1:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script> 
    <link href="/newsite/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    speed: 500,
    });
    });

    </script>
```

## 2:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
var customSearchOptions = {};
var orderByOptions = {};
orderByOptions['keys'] = [{label: 'Relevance', key: ''},{label: 'Date', key: 'date'}];
customSearchOptions['enableOrderBy'] = true;
customSearchOptions['orderByOptions'] = orderByOptions;  var customSearchControl = new       google.search.CustomSearchControl(
'001660792890902641363:fw8od_tpdvm', customSearchOptions);
customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
options.setAutoComplete(true);
options.enableSearchboxOnly("http://www.google.com/cse?cx=001660792890902641363:fw8od_tpdvm");
customSearchControl.draw('cse-search-form', options);
}, true);
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.google.com/cse/style/look/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

I already tried using $j = jQuery.noConflict(); within the first part of the coding, but it didn't work. Almost all answers I searched to this problem suggested doing this, yet it won't solve my problem.

Comment: what makes you think they are conflicting? what kind of error are you getting in console?

Comment: @VolkanUlukut Well, the boxslider on the index page works fine, and the google search shows up - however, I cannot click within the search box unless i'm at the very edge (past the slider). the search works on all other pages (because they don't have a box slider). also, when i commented out the slider, it worked fine. the website is here http://moe365.org/ if you want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

remove this line `padding-top: 1000px;` from `.bx-wrapper .bx-page` in your css file.
that is overlapping your google search. also you seem to have that class defined twice, you need to remove from both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Volkan in his Feb. 10, 2014 answer is correct about what causes the problem -- an invisible boundary around the slider that overlaps the Google Search box. I could not find the padding-top code in the BXSlider CSS described by Volkan. However, I added "margin-top: 15px;" to the container with the slider, which took care of the problem (note that less than 15 px was not enough).